# Where to find v1.8 compatible snapshots?

Tags: nodeos

I am running nodeos version 1.8.1 and cannot find any snapshot repository that is compatible with my node. The snapshots at https://eosnode.tools/snapshots were created with nodeos version <=1.7, which generates snapshots that can't be imported into nodeos version > 1.8.

The error I get when trying to import a snapshot from eosnode.tools to my v1.8.1 nodeos instance:

```
main.cpp:114  
snapshot_validation_exception: Snapshot Validation Exception
Unsupported version of chain snapshot: 1. Supported version must be between 2 and 2 inclusive.
{"version":1,"min":2,"max":2}
nodeos  chain_snapshot.hpp:31 validate
```

Does anyone know of an alternative to the tool above that has version 1.8 compatible snapshots for EOS mainnet?

Answer (score 4):

You can use these 2 sites. I personally used the eossweden one

http://snapshots.eossweden.org/

https://snapshots.eosnation.io/